# Physical web on Chrome OSX

Tags: eddystone

Is it possible for the Chrome on OSX to scan for a device/beacon advertising Eddystone URL without having the user go through the device selection dialog and pair ? navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice shows a dialog and the user has to select the device and pair. Is there an api that can get the Eddystone URL on chrome browser without having to pair with the device ?

Comment: I do not believe this is possible as of March 2017, but I hope to hear someone answer otherwise based on info about newer Chrome updates.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is a security concern that requires the user to manually pair each time. We are working on streamlining this connection if it comes from an Eddystone URL and Physical Web scanner as the user has already picked the item. However, getting this pipelined properly so the hand off is done correctly takes a bit of work. We're working on it but don't have anything concrete to say on timelines.

Scott Jenson
Chrome Team

Answer (score 0):

As Scott [said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42619151/422957), it is not yet possible for now (March 2017) but we're working on it.

Specification has started at https://webbluetoothcg.github.io/web-bluetooth/#dom-bluetooth-referringdevice if you want to have a look though. In short, we're going to use a new `navigator.bluetooth.referringDevice` object to access the Bluetooth device (beacon) that caused the navigation.